# Is there any organization that would hunt force sensitive animals?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, animals

There seems to be a lot of force sensitive animals, some of them rare. Did anyone set out to hunt of the rare ones and why?

I'm much more interested in organisations than individual hunters, but if there are individuals then that would also be nice to know about.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ysalamir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I'd probably point at the Jedi. Their organisation spends a considerable amount of their time hunting out midi-chlorians, described in [the Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian) as

> "intelligent microscopic life forms that lived symbiotically inside
>   the cells of all living things".

And in the Legends series of comics we see Jedi hunting, trapping and taming force sensitive [Akk dogs](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Akk_dog)

Answer (score 0):

There is a species, and that's kind of stretching it. As of the canon TV series *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* (Season 3 final two episodes), it is revealed that **Trandoshans** will capture any being that they can find and release it onto Trandosha's moon Wasskah, in order to hunt them. Many of those beings include Jedi Padawans and younglings.